# Generating and Saving WrightMap chats as pdf in R

Tags: pdf

I'm new to Item reseponse, I have generated a wrightmap to visualise the reseponse levels of difficulty. My interest is in saving the outputs as a pdf so I can have these graphs in one folder when I run the code. How best can I acheive this

I have generated the code below

```
pdf(file="~/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/Work/Random assignments/S3USL_MOCK_UCE_PRETEST_2023_1A_Wright_Map.pdf", paper='a4r',width = 30, height = 18)



wrightMap(thetas = WLEestimates.mod1, thresholds = thresholds.mod1, new=TRUE,
                
                label.items.rows = 3, show.thr.lab = TRUE, thr.lab.text=thr.lab
                
                , thr.sym.col.fg = threshold.symbol.colors,
                
                thr.sym.col.bg = threshold.symbol.colors,thr.sym.pch=threshold.symbols,
                
                thr.sym.cex=1.0,
                
                main.title=test.name, thr.lab.pos=3,
                
                axis.persons = "Person distribution", axis.items = "Items"
                
)


dev.off() #close the graphics window
```

The above code genrates an empty pdf which can not even open, any help will be highly appreciated